# Closing ThickBox Modal Window

Tags: javascript, thickbox

I'm using a ThickBox on a client's site to display a modal form. It's working well, except I can't get it to close. I'm sending modal=true so the title doesn't display, but I'm using divs as buttons to save information or close the box. From the examples I've seen I should be able to just call tb_remove() and that should take care of it, but it's not working at all.

```
<div style="clear: both;">
        <div class="buttons" onclick="javascript:tb_remove()">
            <h2>Cancel</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <h2>Save</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you getting any javascript errors? Check the console. Also, I would much rather write it like this:

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="buttons">
        <h2>Cancel</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <h2>Save</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $('.buttons').click(function() {
        tb_remove();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#wrap {clear:both;}
```

Comment: I'm not getting any javascript errors. I changed the formatting to what you have in the example as well and still no luck.

Comment: From what I've been able to find, it actually is calling the tb_remove() function in the JavaScript, it's just not closing the window.